# ODBC Source with SQL command includes parameter very slow

Tags: ssis, odbc, recordset

I've a SSIS Package with a final result of 5K records, but it runs for like 6 hours.
What did we build?

We have setup a DFT  with an ODBC Source that doesnt do anything more then

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE A
```

(40K Records, I need this ID as a parameter for my SQL command).

Next Step is a Recordset Destination where i save all the ID's as an object.

After these steps it continues in a Foreach loop container with Enumerator Foreach Ado Enumerator.
Ado Object variable is the object i created in the first steps.and the mode we use is Rows in the first table. Then we setup a variable mapping in the container named Input.

In the container we put a another DFT.

ODBC Source.Sqlcommand:

```
"select * from Function_B("+ (DT_WSTR, 6) @[User::Input]+",1,0,1)"
```

The last 3 parameters are always the same only the ID does switch.

In the DFC i put a ODBC Source with the following SQL Statement:

> select * from function_B(0,1,0,1)

and an OLED DB Destination.

It works, but for something as small as 40K records and a final output of 5K should be able to do that much faster in my opinion than the 5/6 hours it runs now.

Thankyou in advance.